# Can't build PHP 8.0.15 with-openssl

Tags: php, ubuntu, openssl

I try to build php 8.0.15 from source. I executed `./configure --with-openssl`.
If I execute `make` then I get this (last block):

```
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/build/php-8.0.15/ext/openssl/openssl.c:46:
/usr/include/openssl/rsa.h:289:29: note: expected ‘RSA *’ {aka ‘struct rsa_st *’} but argument is of type ‘const struct rsa_st *’
  289 |                        RSA *rsa, int padding);
      |                        ~~~~~^~~
make: *** [Makefile:638: ext/openssl/openssl.lo] Error 1
```

What can I do?

---

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)

Comment: What Ubuntu version? What OpenSSL version?

Comment: 20.22 LTS is not a thing, do you mean 22.04 LTS?

Comment: Sorry, you are right

Comment: Looks like PHP 8.0 expects OpenSSL v1, and Ubuntu 22.04 is using OpenSSL v3. I'd recommend just using the [Ondrej PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) if you want a PHP version other than what comes with 22.04 by default.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Ondrej only supports PHP 8.0.19, as the closest version to 8.0.15. Guess it is not possible.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, I also tried to build 8.0.19, but I get the same error.

Comment: Ondrej has 7.4, 8.0, and 8.1 for Ubuntu 22.04. You should always use the latest patch level of a particular minor version, it's guaranteed to be backward compatible. I.e., don't use 8.0.15 specifically, use whatever the latest 8.0.* is.

Comment: I have the same project on mutliple different servers for different companies. My supervisor always wants me to use the exact versions on all systems so that the behaviour will be exactly the same and no new bugs arise. But I understand that it is not possible in ubuntu and we probably need another OS.

Comment: Ubuntu isn't your problem, and switching to a different OS is going to be a huge amount of work for no gain. It makes no sense to restrict to a specific patch level of PHP, you should always use the latest patch level of your desired minor version. See [semver.org](https://semver.org/) -- patch levels don't change functionality. If you're concerned so much about running on a new patch level, then just run your testing suite against it first. Regardless, you should update all the other servers to 8.0.19 anyway.

Comment: Yes, but it is a huge project and testing would take alot of time since we have not enough workers available.